# How to make Bourbon Neat not responsive

Tags: bourbon, neat

I know this might sound weird, but I need to know how can I make Neat not-responsive?

Comment: I'm working on an "out-dated" layout, and I just need to have a better structure and cleaner code for now.

Comment: You can set a variable $max-width anywhere in your sass file after the bourbon and neat import to your desired width.

Answer (score 2):

Open _outer-container.scss out of neat/grid and add just replace `max-width: $max-width` to `width: $max-width`.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have your `outer-container` set the `min-width` for the same size of your container.

```
section {
  @include outer-container;
  min-width: 1088px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

do something like this

**ie.scss**

```
.ie8 {
    // Force IE8 to not be responsive
    //
    body {
        width: 1100px !important;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    * {
        max-width: none;
    }
}
```

**header.js**

```
if (Modernizr.mq('only all')) {
// initialise only for devices
}
```